# Nginx Too Many Redirects when using variable in proxy pass, works fine when passing value in directly

Tags: nginx

Nginx config is causing too many redirects when using a variable in proxy pass. This is an attempt to use NGINX to reverse proxy to resources in a private subnet. The reverse proxy works fine when using the DNS record directly in proxy pass, yet when passing in a variable it causes too many redirects.

NGINX Config: Which DOES NOT WORK

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    server_name $host;
    rewrite ^/$ https://$host/_dashboards redirect;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    set $domain_endpoint "${elasticsearch_endpoint}";
    set $cognito_endpoint "${cognito_host}";

    location /_dashboards {
        # Forward requests to Dashboards
        proxy_pass https://$domain_endpoint/_dashboards;

        # Handle redirects to Cognito
        proxy_redirect https://$cognito_endpoint https://$host;

        # Update cookie domain and path
        proxy_cookie_domain $domain_endpoint $host;
        proxy_cookie_path / /_dashboards/;

        # Response buffer settings
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ \/(log|sign|fav|forgot|change|saml|oauth2) {
        # Forward requests to Cognito
        proxy_pass https://$cognito_endpoint;
    

        # Handle redirects to Dashboards
        proxy_redirect https://$domain_endpoint https://$host;

        # Update cookie domain
        proxy_cookie_domain $cognito_endpoint $host;
    }
}
```

The only difference for a working config. Is the `proxy_pass` under the first `location /_dashboards` is given the DNS record directly like so

```
location /_dashboards {
    # Forward requests to Dashboards
    proxy_pass https://vpc-aws-blah-blah-blah.com/_dashboards;
```

When viewing network traffic in the browser. The request appear to be the same. It makes an initial POST request to a login endpoint with a `redirect_uri` in the url parameters.

The difference is that after the intial POST the working version makes one GET request, while the non-working version makes repeated GET request

Comment: What are `${elasticsearch_endpoint}` and `${cognito_host}`? Where are those variables come from? Also I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with `server_name $host;`.

Comment: These variables are fed in from Terraform, I can SSH onto the machine and see that they are present. They look no different than if I type the variable in directly into the nginx config. 

Truthfully I don't know what I am doing with server name either I have put some pieces together from 

https://github.com/aws-samples/opensearch-in-vpc/blob/main/opensearch-in-vpc-module/proxy_instance_init_script.sh

and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-outside-vpc-nginx/

Comment: You can't use environment variables in nginx config unless you are using something like OpenResty (and if you are, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800071/unable-to-use-environment-variables-in-lua-code) is the solution). Some workarounds described in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf) ServerFault thread.

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass https://$domain_endpoint;`

Comment: Removing `_dashboards` worked. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. Any idea why this was happening ? Was it stuck in a dashboard loop ? @RichardSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
> request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
> matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

You have `/_dashboards` in both the `location` and `proxy_pass`, therefore the replacement changes nothing. So you can remove the optional URI part from the `proxy_pass` statement.

Also, in the same document:

> When variables are used in proxy_pass ..., if URI is specified in the
> directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original
> request URI.

So, when you started using variables, if the original request was `/_dashboards/foo`, the upstream server would only ever receive `/_dashboards`.

The simplest solution was to remove `/_dashboards` from the `proxy_pass` statement.