# Environment Variables in LUA

Tags: nginx, redis, lua

I have a Lua Script which Logins to the Redis and Process some Query to enable IP Based Blocking

Below is the Redis Config I am using in my Lua script and to run this script at every hit to the webserver I use the access_by_lua directive in my Nginx conference

```
--- Redis Configuration
local redis_host = "100.2.4.4"
local redis_port = 6379
local redis_timeout = 30
local cache_ttl     = 3600
```

I would like to use an environment Variable in the reds_host and the port rather than static value
Any Help is appreciated

**Note:**

I have tried it as below, but no luck

```
--- Redis Configuration
local redis_host = os.getenv("redis_auth_host")
local redis_port = os.getenv("redis_auth_port")
local redis_timeout = 30
local cache_ttl     = 3600
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800071/unable-to-use-environment-variables-in-lua-code

Comment: not exact, some similar one i found here

Comment: Saw it already but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Redis runs Lua script in a sandbox, which disables global variables, with a few exceptions. In your case, `os` is a disabled global variable, so you cannot use it.

In order to avoid hard-coding the host and port, you can set them in Redis' key space, i.e. setting host and port as key-value pairs in Redis, and get them with `redis.call()` method.

```
local redis_host = redis.call("get", "host")
local redis_port = redis.call("get", "port")
```